# what is crossdomain cookies? are they really useful ? if so when is it used

Tags: php, session, cookies

What is a crossdomain cookie ?

what are they meant for ?

Can you give some senarios where crossdomain cookies are useful. Would appreciate for in depth explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you referring to accepting cookies from other sites? These are usually disabled in modern browsers, which only accept cookies from the site whose address is in address bar and not others.

The reason they were banned was they made trivial to track users between collaborating websites, although the advantage provided by this banning is dubious (there are equally effective methods available).

Note that a website can also define a cookie whose scope is larger than the current domain, as long as it doesn't ascend to a top-level domain. For instance `meta.stackoverflow.com` could define a cookie whose scope included `whatever.stackoverflow.com` and even `stackoverflow.com`, but not `example.com`.

Comment: m not sure of that... Hence the question raised on my head. Moreover I  don't think crossdomain cookies are blocked by browsers.

Comment: @nepsdotin Maybe that's what I described in the last paragraph, no?

Answer (score 0):

Cross domain cookies are cookies that can be read by website code running on different domains. They are very useful for tracking user behavior and otherwise violating people's privacy, so **don't use them!**